# Can I set a longer timeout for protractor to connect to selenium driver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Running my protractor tests remotely (jenkins) leads to timeout error sometimes. That is not deterministic.

```
Starting selenium standalone server...
[launcher] Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[launcher] Process exited with error code 1

/opt/jenkins.dir/workspace/my-jenkins-job/integration-test/ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/promise.js:1761
      throw error;
            ^
Error: Timed out waiting for the WebDriver server at http://10.97.193.53:4455/wd/hub
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at onResponse (/opt/jenkins.dir/workspace/my-jenkins-job/integration-test/ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:87:11)
    at /opt/jenkins.dir/workspace/my-jenkins-job/integration-test/ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/util.js:42:21
    at /opt/jenkins.dir/workspace/my-jenkins-job/integration-test/ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver/http/http.js:96:5
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous> (/opt/jenkins.dir/workspace/my-jenkins-job/integration-test/ui/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:145:7)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Socket.socketErrorListener (http.js:1548:9)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at net.js:441:14
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:448:13)
```

However when I run the tests locally in my mac there is no problem and the tests run perfectly.

I have tried to start the selenium servers manually in the remote machines and I have realised that sometimes it works immediately and sometimes I have to wait up to one minute.

My question is: **Is there any way to tell protractor to wait longer for the webdriver to connect?**

*Environment details*

- Machine: Red Hat 4.4.7-11
- Protractor version: 1.8.0
- Selenium Server Standalone: 2.45.0

Answer (score 0):

You can specify it by using driver.wait function.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var protractor = require('protractor');

var driver = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer("seleniumAddress").build();
var browser = protractor.wrapDriver(driver);

browser.driver.wait(driver.getWindowHandle(), 5000, 'Server should start within 5 seconds');
```

References :

1. http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.wait
2. http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebDriver.prototype.getWindowHandle

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it should solve your issue.  Use the **seleniumServerStartTimeout** option in your **protractor.conf.js** file to bump up the timeout from the default 30 seconds to something longer like 90 seconds:

```
exports.config = { 
  seleniumServerStartTimeout: 90000
};
```

I experienced the same issue on a CentOS 7 VM.  For whatever reason the selenium server seems to take wildly different amounts of time to start up each time, and can sometimes exceed the default timeout.